# consolidating and decommissioning data across network

Tags: windows, filesystems, network-shares

I've recently been tasked to consolidate our data footprint across our network.  We have several terabytes of data that has existed on multiple servers and I would estimate that about 30-40% of the data is useless.  I would classify 'useless' data as data that hasn't been touched in over 7 years because someone moved it to a new location and never cleaned up the old one, or its just irrelevant and old.

My question is...

Is there a tool that would allow me to scan large amounts of data to help me identify possible orphaned directories on our network?

Comment: Orphaned in relation to what? You mean unique? No duplicates? No references? I would not recommend any automated methods that are destructive in any way, and scanning will destroy last access times of the files. Data is sacred. I'm afraid this is a horrible job that necessarily needs meticulous attention to detail.

Comment: Do you just want a tool that will scan for files older than 7 years??

Comment: @soandos: i think that would be a good start.

Comment: @Andy: I plan on moving the suspect data to a tape or external drive.  I don't plan on doing any deletion.

Comment: are there any other criterion?

Comment: not that i can think of.

Comment: @Michael, OK. We just postpone judgement day with bigger and bigger disks when a sort out is looming! find ./ -type d -mtime +2555 to find dirs older than 7 years, find ./ -type f -mtime +2555 to find files...

Comment: Just noticed this is a windows thing - there should be a windows equivalent, or install cygwin to give a windows machine access to linux command line tools. JP Software's 4NT has a great command line interface for doing recursive dir searches with date ranges and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, search for DoubleKiller - I found it really useful for identifying duplicate files through terabytes of stuff, it has lots of search options and constraints on which directories to scan. It's a useful tool for the arsenal, but as with anything reading files it'll destroy access times, if they might be needed in the future.

Comment: cool! Running it now :)

Comment: great, glad to be able to help...